# How to add spaces between each capital letter inside double quotes using Regex in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using Regex Find/Replace in Notepad++, I am trying to add spaces between each capital letter inside double quotes:

```
.Label("ATextWhichHasCapitalLetters")
.Label(Constants.DefinedLabel)
.Label("AnotherTextWhichHasCapitalLetters")
```

The result should be:

```
.Label("A Text Which Has Capital Letters")
.Label(Constants.DefinedLabel)
.Label("Another Text Which Has Capital Letters")
```

I tried many expressions but failed to get the expected result.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share what expressions you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the non-word-boundary expression `\B` and a look ahead for a capital letter to find the insertion points, with the rest of the look ahead requiring exactly 1 quote following:

```
Search: \B(?=[A-Z][^"]*"[^"]*$)
Replace: <space>
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/Y5XoeYF5pD).

Answer (score 4):

```
((?<=\w)[A-Z])(?!(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

You can use this and replace by `$1` or `\1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iJ7bT6/14

Answer (score 1):

or this pattern

```
(?:^[^"]*"|\G)[^"]*?\K(?<![" ])[A-Z]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/325)